# Blog advertisement disappeared after one click

Tags: javascript, blogs, adsense

I need help, I have a blog with blogspot platform and a blog without advertising. If visitors already clicked your ad once the ad will automatically disappear for a few hours.

Ad script which I modified:

```
<div id='atas'>
<ins class='adsbygoogle' data-ad-client='ca-pub-sensor' data-ad-slot='sensor' style='display:inline-block;width:300px;height:600px'/><script>(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>

<ins class='adsbygoogle' data-ad-client='ca-pub-Sensor' data-ad-slot='Sensor' id='Kanan' style='display:inline-block;width:300px;height:600px'/><script>(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>

</div>
```

Comment: Please make your question more clear... What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I would like if the ad on my blog already in clicks he would disappear for a few hours and then reappeared